# Why was this spam flag declined, even though it's obvious spam?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, spam

I flagged a post as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57745480/1) revision as spam, it was edited then when a moderator reviewed it, it wasn't spam and it was declined.

Comment: That's clever. Depending on the view in the Mod dashboard, we'll only see the first few lines.  It'd be easier than you'd expect to hide spam after a few lines.  Also the formatting in the mod dashboard doesn't reflect the formatting we see as end-users.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Is it possible to change the flag to helpful?

Comment: One declined flag is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Robert is right. While it's technically possible (in the sense that it may work if the stars are aligned) to reset a flag; it's so fraught with possible side-effects and downsides that we don't do it (I've never heard Shog audibly sigh through chat but when we start asking the CMs about the mechanics of reversing flags it is nothing but sighs due to the nature of the software behind it).  Don't worry about a few declined flags; worry when you start getting dozens.

Comment: I've also pinged the moderator so they could respond to your question.

Comment: Interesting. On one hand it looks like a terrible question with terrible formatting. On the other hand the XML is literally an Atom feed of what appears to be a really suspicious and smelly site.

Comment: @BoltClock Looking back through the OPs other questions; it looks like they spend a lot of time scraping bitcoin sites.

Comment: @George Stocker: Wonder if they're data mining to facilitate Bitcoin mining or something?

Answer (score 17):

I declined the flag and edited the post because it seemed like a very very poor question with an incredibly bad formatting.

The post had few parts which led me to believe that it was a clear question:

> XML FILE :
>
> PHP FILE :

Both of which are clear indicators that the poster was trying to write some PHP code and wanted to share the XML File as data.

> Object Error came

Which again indicated that the user had a problem with the said PHP script and they received an "object error".

The user also had a nice history of some badly formatted questions, all in PHP, so it was pretty clear that it was a bad question and not Spam.

The reason why I didn't delete it then was because I wanted to give the OP an opportunity to improve the post, if possible. Also, given that it was closed, the post would have been roombad.

I'm still not sure that it is spam. Anyway, the next time you see bare links hanging around, try to see the original source of the post. It might be that the poster has very poorly formatted their post.